How to simulate correlated data with specified min and max and cov and mean in R
I want to simulate data with fixed mean and covariance matrix as multivariable distribution in which generated data must be in a range [floor , ceiling].
Using MASS::mvrnorm I can not specify the range (max and min). Is there any solution for this problem?
I read all the related topics and documentation but could not find a solution where you can also set the max and min of generated data
xy <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = 500, mu = c(mean_a, mean_b), Sigma = Sigma)
colnames(xy) <- c("a", "b")
xydf <- data.frame(xy)
head(xydf)


I think this is more of a stats question than a programming question.  What joint distribution do you want to end up with?

This is actually a fairly challenging question. Are the min and max values symmetric about the mean? If so, and if the requested covariance matrix and the number of samples are reasonably consistent with the requested min/max, then sampling a multivariate normal and then truncating will probably work reasonably well (i.e., truncating won't mess up the mean and covariance matrix too badly). Otherwise, this is definitely going to be a challenge. Adding some more context to the question would definitely help: why do you want to do this?

Whether this is easy or hard depends very much on whether the mean vector and covariance matrix refer to the distribution before or after truncation. If you want to specify mean and covariance on the untruncated distribution, then apply truncation, then as specified in the link you quoted, the tmvtnorm package will do this:
library(tmvtnorm)
set.seed(101)
x <- rtmvnorm(100000, mean = c(1, 2), sigma = matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2), nrow = 2),
          lower = c(0, 2), upper = c(1, 3))

Check results:
options(digits = 3); var(x)
        [,1]    [,2]
[1,] 0.07160 0.00555
[2,] 0.00555 0.07749

You can see that the covariance matrix is nowhere near the original specified set of values; it has been vastly reduced by truncation. Apparently, though, this is also how the scipy.truncnorm function works. (The problem is much harder if you want a random variable that matches the specified moments after truncation — for some choices of truncation and moments, it would actually be impossible, e.g. if you wanted a range of (0,1) and a standard deviation of 10000 ...)

This code you provided does not seem to track variances correctly. I found a repo implementing a 2016 algorithm which seems to work, the only problem is that the variance varies so much but mean is ok.
github.com/brunzema/truncated-mvn-sampler
